# Looking for a midrash about Moshe not being born perfect

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, moshe-rabbeinu

Looking for a midrash about Moshe (preferably in English) that says that Moshe rabenu was not born perfect but over the early part of his life perfected his character...

Comment: one data point here: http://strangeside.com/moshe-moses-was-he-born-perfect/

Comment: Thankso this is what I was looking for. Came up in a conversation recently and was wondering what the source was exactly

Comment: @mbloch https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://forum.otzar.org/download/file.php%3Fid%3D40233&ved=2ahUKEwj0obeunJSAAxWaFlkFHTBmBoAQFnoECBQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2w2pz4XLXLGDRj70rLSdPQ published on order hachochmo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be puzzling because

> the Gemara (Sotah 12) states, “’She saw him, that he was good…’ R.
> Nechemiah says, ‘Fitting for prophecy.’ Others say, ‘He was born
> circumcised.’ And the Sages say, ‘At the time Moshe was born, the
> whole house filled with light. [...]
>
> When Pharoah’s daughter found him it says: ‘And she saw him, the boy.’ It should
> have just said, ‘She saw him.’ Explained R. Yosi bar Chanina, ‘Because
> she saw the Shechinah with him.’”

but [strangeside](http://strangeside.com/moshe-moses-was-he-born-perfect/) has a relevant story referring to your question

> Over a century ago, in 5655/1895, Rav Chaim Yitzchok Aharon, the
> Maggid of Vilkomir, published an eleven-page booklet, “Klil Tiferes,”
> to explode what seemed to be an impossible story. “In this brochure,”
> Rav Chaim Yitzchok Aharon writes, “**we have come to point out that
> the Torah testifies that Moshe Rabbeinu possessed every good virtue at
> birth**, as it says, ‘And she saw him, that he was good…’ (Shemos
> 2:2).
>
> “**However, about fifty years ago, one of the gedolei hador, (the
> “Tiferes Yisroel”) cited an anonymous story in his sefer, at the end
> of Seder Nashim. The story testifies that Moshe was inclined, by
> nature, to have bad middos, such as pride and avarice…** The gaonim of
> our generation agree that this letter must have originated in some
> journal… Therefore, I have written this brochure to prove that this
> story is a total forgery and absolute falsehood…”

see [there](http://strangeside.com/moshe-moses-was-he-born-perfect/) for the full details, too long to quote here

Comment: Perhaps one flaw that Moshe had was that he got angry - occasionally at the wrong things and at the wrong time?

Comment: Degel Machane Efraym also cited as the Tiferet Israel

Comment: You should summarize the story of the painting and why the claim was made.

Comment: have heard that story cited as the most impressive one of moses. ie that he worked on perfecting his character rather than being born perfect

Comment: +1 - In his mishnayos, R' Ruderman actually went over this Tiferes Yisroel with a black marker.